# Scaling Socket.io Node.js App using Cloud Foundry and NginX Build Pack

Tags: node.js, nginx, socket.io, ibm-cloud, cloud-foundry

I am trying to scale my Socket.io Node.js server horizontally using Cloud Foundry (on IBM Cloud).

As of now, my manifest.yml for cf looks like this:

```
applications:
  - name: chat-app-server
    memory: 512M
    instances: 2
    buildpacks:
      - nginx_buildpack
```

This way the deployment goes through, but of course the socket connections between client and server fail because the connection is not sticky.

The official Socket.io documentation gives an example for using NginX for using multiple nodes.
When using a custom nginx.conf file using the Socket.io [template](https://socket.io/docs/v3/using-multiple-nodes/index.html) I am missing some information (highlighted with ???).

```
events { worker_connections 1024; }

http {

  server {
    listen {{port}};
    server_name ???;

    location / {


        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;

        proxy_pass http://nodes;

        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
    }

  }

    upstream nodes {
       # enable sticky session based on IP
       ip_hash;

       server ???:???;
       server ???:???;
  }
}
```

I've tried to find out where cloud foundry runs the two instances specified in the manifest.yml file with no luck.

How do I get the required server addresses/ports from cloud foundry?
Is there a way to obtain this information dynamically from CF?

I am deploying my application using `cf push`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't used Socket.IO before, so I may be off base, but from a quick read of the docs, it seems like things should just work.

Two points from the docs:

a.) When using WebSockets, this is a non-issue. Cloud Foundry fully supports WebSockets. Hopefully, most of your clients can do that.

b.) When falling back to long polling, you need sticky sessions. Cloud Foundry supports sticky sessions out-of-the-box, so again, this should just work. There is one caveat though regarding CF's support of sticky sessions, it expects the session cookie name to be `JSESSIONID`.

Again, I'm not super familiar with Socket.IO, but I suspect it's probably using a different session cookie name by default (most things outside of Java do). You just need to change the session cookie name to `JSESSIONID` and sticky sessions should work.

TIP: you can check the session cookie name by looking at your cookies in your browser's dev tools.

Final note. You don't need Nginx here at all. Gorouter, which is Cloud Foundry's routing layer, will handle the sticky session support for you.

Comment: Thank you very much.
It looks like NginX doesn’t work together with Cloud Foundry deployments even though they offer a custom buildpack.
Adding the JSESSIONID cookie to requests was indeed the right way to do it. 
In Express.JS you can use express-session as middleware adding a custom cookie.  
This solution works perfectly for Chrome, but causes problems with Safari and Incognito-Tabs in Chrome. 
I am getting lots of 400 - Bad Request messages.
Any idea what causes these errors and is there a way to avoid them?

Comment: Nginx works perfectly fine on CF. It's just not necessary for what you are doing here. There's no apparent reason to add another proxy layer. It will only add latency and create more work for you.

Comment: I don't know about the 400's. Check your browser's dev tools to confirm it's getting the Set-Cookie header back from your app and that it has the correct cookie name. Also, look at your app and see why it's returning a 400. That typically means the app doesn't like something about the request being made by the client, but only your app would know exactly what is not correct.